# Merged question not displaying correctly

Tags: support, specific-question, merged-questions

I merged [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/how-do-you-know-when-you-are-tired-of-programming-in-your-life-closed) into [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/how-do-you-know-when-you-are-tired-of-programming-in-your-life) and all appeared to go OK.

But as you can see:

[image]

there's no indication that it was merged. If you look a the mod menu you can see that the system acknowledges that it was merged:

[image]

So, is this a quirk, bug or something I shouldn't worry about?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the post having been migrated before. The merge events appear properly in both questions' post revisions.

Comment: @Jon - I did check that too (at least on the master question).

Comment: Yeah, it's probably just a display issue.

Comment: Probably the same thing reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26320/no-closed-reason-displayed-on-question-migrated-from-so-to-sf-to-su).

Comment: @Michael - possibly, but the merge is within the same site, not a migration to a 3rd site.

Comment: Hey, ChrisF - why'd you merge in *that* direction? Medusa was the original author...

Comment: @Shog9 - It seemed to be the right way to me. I know the Stack Overflow version was the "original", but as the questions were identical ultimately it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, as with all "merged then something weird happened", just delete the other copies. We auto-redirect anyway, for all users with < 10k rep, they'll go to the merged version.